# Calculating moving median within group

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, median, rolling-computation

I want to perform rolling median on price column over 4 days back, data will be groupped by date. So basically I want to take prices for a given day and all prices for 4 days back and calculate median out of these values.

Here are the sample data:

```
id      date        price
1637027 2020-01-21  7045204.0
280955  2020-01-11  3590000.0
782078  2020-01-28  2600000.0
1921717 2020-02-17  5500000.0
1280579 2020-01-23  869000.0
2113506 2020-01-23  628869.0
580638  2020-01-25  650000.0
1843598 2020-02-29  969000.0
2300960 2020-01-24  5401530.0
1921380 2020-02-19  1220000.0
853202  2020-02-02  2990000.0
1024595 2020-01-27  3300000.0
565202  2020-01-25  3540000.0
703824  2020-01-18  3990000.0
426016  2020-01-26  830000.0
```

I got close with combining rolling and groupby:

```
df.groupby('date').rolling(window = 4, on = 'date')['price'].median()
```

But this seems to add one row per each index value and by median definition, I am not able to somehow merge these rows to produce one result per row.

Result now looks like this:

```
date        date      
2020-01-10  2020-01-10          NaN
            2020-01-10          NaN
            2020-01-10          NaN
            2020-01-10    3070000.0
            2020-01-10    4890000.0
                            ...    
2020-03-11  2020-03-11    4290000.0
            2020-03-11    3745000.0
            2020-03-11    3149500.0
            2020-03-11    3149500.0
            2020-03-11    3149500.0
Name: price, Length: 389716, dtype: float64
```

It seems it just deleted 3 first values and then just printed price value.

Is it possible to get one lagged / moving median value per one date?

Comment: df.rolling(window = 4, on = 'date')['price'].median()  ?

Comment: seems to just delete first 3 rows and then prints price per index, not day

Comment: oh, now I understand, every date has more than 1 row, let me see...

Comment: haven't found a way but iteration, here goes:  pd.DataFrame([[x, df[(df['date']<=x)&(df['date']>=x-pd.Timedelta('4d'))]['price'].median()] for x in df['date']],
             columns=['date','4d_median']).drop_duplicates()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `rolling` with a frequency window of 5 days to get today and last 4 days, then `drop_duplicates` to keep the last row per day. First create a `copy` (if you want to keep the original one), `sort_values` per date and ensure the date column is datetime

```
#sort and change to datetime
df_f = df[['date','price']].copy().sort_values('date')
df_f['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_f['date'])

#create the column rolling
df_f['price'] = df_f.rolling('5D', on='date')['price'].median()

#drop_duplicates and keep the last row per day
df_f = df_f.drop_duplicates(['date'], keep='last').reset_index(drop=True)

print (df_f)

         date      price
0  2020-01-11  3590000.0
1  2020-01-18  3990000.0
2  2020-01-21  5517602.0
3  2020-01-23   869000.0
4  2020-01-24  3135265.0
5  2020-01-25  2204500.0
6  2020-01-26   849500.0
7  2020-01-27   869000.0
8  2020-01-28  2950000.0
9  2020-02-02  2990000.0
10 2020-02-17  5500000.0
11 2020-02-19  3360000.0
12 2020-02-29   969000.0
```

Comment: Trying to do the same with another column `age` and I need to filter the values before rolling. I've tried as:

`df_f['medAge'] = df_f[df_f['age'] >= 35].rolling('5D', on='date')['age'].median()`
 
but it sometimes produces the right result and sometimes `NaN` although values are there. Any ideas why?

Comment: @Musisak it is because of index alignement. let's say `df_f` as 10 rows overall, but because of the filter, `df_f[df_f['age'] >= 35]` is only 6 rows, then after the `rolling` it is still 6 rows, but you assign these 6 values in `df_f` that has 10 rows, the missing index are filled with `NaN`. Check if the `Nan` are only where the age is below 35!

Answer (score 1):

This is a step by step process.  There are probably more efficient methods of getting what you want.  Note, if you have time information for your dates, you would need to drop that information before grouping by date.

```
import pandas as pd
import statistics as stat
import numpy as np

# Replace with you data import
df = pd.read_csv('random_dates_prices.csv')

# Convert your date to a datetime
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

# Sort your data by date
df = df.sort_values(by = ['date'])

# Create group by object
dates = df.groupby('date')

# Reformat dataframe for one row per day, with prices in a nested list
df = pd.DataFrame(dates['price'].apply(lambda s: s.tolist()))

# Extract price lists to a separate list
prices = df['price'].tolist()

# Initialize list to store past four days of prices for current day
four_days = []

# Loop over the prices list to combine the last four days to a single list
for i in range(3, len(prices), 1):
    x = i - 1
    y = i - 2
    z = i - 3
    four_days.append(prices[i] + prices[x] + prices[y] + prices[z])

# Initialize a list to store median values
medians = []

# Loop through four_days list and calculate the median of the last for days for the current date
for i in range(len(four_days)):
    medians.append(stat.median(four_days[i]))

# Create dummy zero values to add lists create to dataframe    
four_days.insert(0, 0)
four_days.insert(0, 0)
four_days.insert(0, 0)
medians.insert(0, 0)
medians.insert(0, 0)
medians.insert(0, 0)

# Add both new lists to data frames
df['last_four_day_prices'] = four_days
df['last_four_days_median'] = medians

# Replace dummy zeros with np.nan
df[['last_four_day_prices', 'last_four_days_median']] = df[['last_four_day_prices', 'last_four_days_median']].replace(0, np.nan)

# Clean data frame so you only have a single date a median value for past four days
df_clean = df.drop(['price', 'last_four_day_prices'], axis=1)
```

Comment: This is interesting, but it would fail if you don't have all dates. Because when you do `prices[i] + prices[x] + prices[y] + prices[z]` you would grab prices for days not within the right time range.

Comment: I don't believe it would fail if not all dates are included.  The data I generated, did not have all dates and this works.  Since we sort the dataframe by date, any dates in the data will be in order.  Then when the price information is extracted to a list, we no longer have dates, only date price lists.  So when we loop through prices, we are subtracting from the list index, which does not represent one day.

Comment: The code works, but I have some doubt about the result. Try it yourself with the OP data: for the date 2020-02-17, there is only one value of  5500000 and the closest date before is 2020-02-02 so far from 4 days before. so the median over the last 4 days is 5500000 but with your method, I get 3145000.0 because it uses the value from the previous date available in the list, even if they are not within 4 days

Comment: Ah, yes you are correct.  We are reading the ask differently.  If the ask is the median for the last four days, regardless of if those dates exist in the data, this won't provide the result you are looking for.